# I need to write a file in jar

Tags: java, jar, inputstream, executable-jar

I need to write  a file in a jar. Suppose to have this structure

```
progetto
   src
     grafica
        finestraprincipale.java
        indice_corrente.txt
```

I need to write "hello" in my indice_corrente.txt from myfinestraprincipale.java

I must load in this way

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Grafica/indice_corrente.txt");
```

But for me it is not important read but I need to write in "indice_corrente.txt".
Anyone can help me?

Comment: You can't. ``getResourceAsStream`` gives you an ``InputStream`` that you can only read from. To modify that file you would need to modify the jar file itself.

Comment: @f1sh how can obtain url's indice_corrente.txt because I do getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("src/grafica/indice_corrente.txt") is give me null so I don't know where I take url to put in printwriter

Comment: if that gives you ``null`` you cannot even read from the file right now. Take a look at where the file is inside your finished jar. Again: You won't be able to write to it.

Comment: I have the "indice_corrente.txt" in to the jar and not near in the same jar folder and I want in this way . is it possibile write this file ?if yes how?

Comment: **No,** it is not possible.  It will never be possible.  It is not correct for an application to try to modify its own .jar.  The file in your .jar should be treated as a read-onlty prototype;  if you want to write a newer version, put it in the user’s home directory or in a temporary file.